# How to get a Makefile from qmake

Tags: qt, qt4, makefile, qmake

Given an x.pro file, how can I produce a makefile? Running qmake x.pro produces an x.pbproj directory without a Makefile.

Thanks

Edit: Adding info. about the pro file and platform.
I am running this on Mac OS X (10.6). The same pro file used to produce a Makefile under OpenSUSE. Here is a snippet of the pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = x
DEPENDPATH +=
INCLUDEPATH +=
CONFIG += qt debug
QT = core network
# Input
LIBS += -lcryptopp
HEADERS += x.hpp
..... # rest of the header files
```

Comment: Please provide some details in your question, like the text of the .pro file, and what platform it's on.

Comment: On Linux it produces a Makefile in the same location as it puts all *.o files by default.

Comment: Updated the question with the text of the pro file along with the platform

Comment: For Qt5.13, a complete list of mkspecs can be found in each platform's (build toolchain's) mkspecs directory, e.g. Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\mingw73_64\mkspecs or Qt\Qt5.13.1\5.13.1\msvc2017_64\mkspecs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I gues that you're using Mac OS X

`qmake -spec macx-g++ x.pro` on Mac OS X to generate Makefile

`qmake x.pro` on linux to generate Makefile (default behaviour)

`qmake -spec win32-g++ x.pro` on Windows to generate Makefile

Comment: Consider also setting the environment variable QMAKESPEC to macx-g++. That would save time.