# Missing separator Qt 5.4 makefile

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I am using Qt 5.4 and mingw64 4.8.1

so i am using `qmake` to make the MakeFile, however when i use mingw32-make to make the executable I get the "missing separator" error on line 62

the code around this line is as follows:

```
{.}.cpp{release\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Forelease\ @<<
    $<
<<
```

before the $ signs there are tab characters, and the last line is line 62,
CXX is defined as `cl` although when i changed the definition g++ it didnt work (as i had seen this as a suggested solution elsewhere)

The entire Makefile is available here: http://pastebin.com/GVKj1Vjs

thanks in advance for any help you can offer

Comment: That target line looks very odd to me. I have no idea what it is trying to do or indicate. Actually, that looks like perhaps it is an `nmake` makefile. Are you sure `qmake` put out `(GNU) make` makefiles and not `nmake` makefiles. Can you choose the output target format when you run `qmake`?

Comment: I deleted the files and ran `qmake` again... the same file was produced and when i tried to use `mingw32-make` it game the same error on the same line. i had a look at the `qmake -h` menu but could not see a way to specify the files... any ideas?

Comment: What command are you using to run `qmake` exactly? Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8586502/258523) help?

Comment: i was just using `qmake` but i guess that since i ended up installing the msvc version of Qt that it didnt end up encoding it for mingw's compiler settings, the windows version of the linked answer did stop the "missing seperator" error, I am now finding code errors though :P thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a Makefile from qmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571687/how-to-get-a-makefile-from-qmake)